# How can I tell exactly what type of .Net project I've created and what DevOps pipeline I should use to build it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-devops, yaml, devops

I am using Azure DevOps with Azure Git and I believe I've created an ASP.Net Core application (`.NET 5.0`) that is my web API (**Project/Solution A**).

I've created a separate solution/project/branch for a `MSTest` project of unit tests that target the other application (web API) to verify the endpoints are all working (**Project/Solution B**)

I'm trying to create a pipeline to build **Project B**, so that I can link the test cases, but when I go to choose the pipeline configuration, I see `ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)` and `ASP.NET Core`.

1. I thought `ASP.NET Core` used `.NET Core`, so how can it be both `ASP.NET Core` and `(.NET Framework)` at the same time?
2. What is the proper way to describe what my project is targeting? ".NET 5.0", ".NET Core", "ASP.NET Core 5.0", "ASP.NET Core", etc?

[image]

[image]

Comment: ASP.NET Core is a web application framework  that doesn't necessarily have to run on .NET Core. ASP.NET Core versions after 2.1 will not be supported on .NET Framework. That's findable with a quick bit of googling - are you sure you did enough research prior to asking this question?

Comment: @mason I've searched, but there's so much ambiguity of the naming conventions, search results aren't clear. So I would have an `ASP.NET Core` project targeting `.NET Core 5.0` it sounds like?

Comment: You should be able to tell just by looking at your project. Are you using ASP.NET Core? Yes? Is that running on .NET 5.0? Yes? You look at your system and find out, then select the build template closest to what you've got.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought ASP.NET Core used .NET Core, so how can it be both ASP.NET Core and (.NET Framework) at the same time?

Use the ASP.NET Core template. That because the template ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) target for the **full .NET Framework**：

[image]

> What is the proper way to describe what my project is targeting? ".NET
> 5.0", ".NET Core", "ASP.NET Core 5.0", "ASP.NET Core", etc?

Personally, the `ASP.NET Core 5.0` should be the proper way to describe your project is targeting. That because we could create the Console application with `.NET 5.0` or a `ASP.NET Core 2.0` project. So, `ASP.NET Core 5.0` can accurately describe your project type and target's .net core version.